# Background color of barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

As I don't have any experience with Android prior to JetPack compose, I'm unable to figure this out.

I'm using the `barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer` but since this is an old library, I need to wrap this in a `AndroidView()` composable. This works and displays the PDF correctly.

```
@Composable
fun PDFView(
    byteArray: ByteArray,
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),

        factory = { context ->
            PDFView(
                ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.PdfView), null
            )
        },
        update = { pdfView ->
            Log.d(TAG, "PDF view UPDATE called")
            pdfView
                .fromBytes(byteArray)
                .autoSpacing(false)
                .spacing(25)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
                .load()
        }
    )
}
```

As per documentation of the lib, setting some spacing and adding a background colour would result in a visual separation of the PDF pages.
Setting the AndroidView's modifier background does not work.
So I tried setting background on `R.style.PDFView` like so (tried several options):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="PdfView" parent="Theme.MyPDFView">
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But this still does not change the background.
To be complete, the `Theme.MyPDFTheme` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyPDFView" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I also tried setting background color in `Theme.kt`

```
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    surface = Color.Green,
    background = Color.Yellow,
```

But the background of the PDFView does not change, yes, device is in light mode.
How can I set the background on this view?

Comment: You can use setBackgroundColor in PDFView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `PDFView` background color with `setBackgroundColor`:

```
factory = { context ->
    PDFView(
        context,
        null
    ).also {
        it.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.toArgb())
    }
},
```

Then the background color set with the `Modifier` will become visible. Full example:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        PDFView(
            context,
            null
        ).also {
            it.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.toArgb())
        }
    },
    update = { pdfView ->
        pdfView
            .fromStream(pdfView.context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.sample))
            .autoSpacing(false)
            .spacing(25)
            .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
            .load()
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Red)
)
```